# JMeter throws many 403 errors

Tags: jmeter

I have been struggling for hours to find out whats wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

1. As per [HTTP Status 403 description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)

   > The HTTP `403 Forbidden` client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

   > This status is similar to `[401`][2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401), but in this case, re-authenticating will make no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource.

   So my expectation is that your user gets authenticated however it doesn't have enough permissions to perform the action your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler is trying to perform so I would double-check your user permissions matrix.
2. There are at least 8 errors in your script

   [image]

   so it worth checking [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries
3. If your application is protected by [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) you need to:

   - supply domain and realm in the HTTP Authorization Manager
   - perform appropriate configuration in krb5.conf file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more details